# eclipse STS - tc Server Instances Won't Start Following STS Update

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

When I start tc Server from STS, I get this error `Server TC7 failed to start` and the following message turns up in the console:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/local/springsource/sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/960/1/.cp/lib/springloaded-1.1.0.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

This has happened the last few times I've updated STS within eclipse. What could be wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the STS' Servers view, right click your server and open Properties. Click Switch Locations and click it again (to get back to your original location), then click Apply and start your server again (you may have to restart eclipse). Everything should work now.

The cause of the problem is that the newer location of spring-loaded which is used to instrument tomcat is not known to your old tc Server's configuration after you update STS. Behind the scenes tc Server starts up with various command line parameters which you can see in your launch configurations (Right click server > Open > Open launch configuration > Arguments tab) and these get out of date when you update. By switching your workspace, STS automatically sets these up for you again using it's updated values. For some reason they don't do this for you automatically when you update STS.